# How to handle the click event for a checkbox present in the preference?

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have created a preference screen and populated it with java code.

I have created a preference with custom layout (my_pref.xml) which contains a `CheckBox`, `ImageView`, `ImageButton` and `TextView`. This looks just like `CheckBoxPreference` with an `ImageButton`.

How do i implement the method for when the `CheckBox` is "ticked"?

```
  PreferenceCategory pr = (PreferenceCategory) findPreference("preference");

          Preference mypref = new Preference(this);
          mypref.setLayoutResource(R.layout.my_pref);
          pr.addPreference(mypref);

        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
```

I am getting the value of `cb = null`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager .getDefaultSharedPreferences(PreferenceDemoActivity.this);     
boolean checkBox = prefs.getBoolean("checkBox", false);    
builder.append("Keep me logged in: " + String.valueOf(checkBox) + "\n");    

textView.setText(builder.toString());
}
```

see this one http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/tag/preferenceactivity/